# Image not displaying when setting it in the UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to build a Cocoa Touch Class that is assigned to my Navigation Controller (in my Storyboard) to display an image in the center of the Navigation Bar. The app builds but the image is not displayed and I cannot figure out why.

[image]

```
class NavBarImg: UINavigationController {


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView(){
        if navigationController == nil {
            return
        }

        let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BarTabsNavLogoWhite")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        let bannerWidth = navigationBar.frame.size.width
        let bannerHeight = navigationBar.frame.size.height

        let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image.size.width / 2
        let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image.size.height / 2

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView  

    }
}
```

Comment: The first line of your `setupView` makes no sense; this code is a subclass of `UINavigationController`, so `self` is your navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an cocoa touch class for UINavigationController > implement code below > assign class to navigation controller in the storyboard.

```
class NavControllerClass: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupNavigationBar()

}

func setupNavigationBar()
{
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BarTabsNavLogoWhite")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = navigationBar.frame
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navigationBar.addSubview(imageView)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are only calling `setupView` in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` (unless there's some code that you are not sharing) and this is just to preview it on the storyboard.
For that to be executed when running the app you need to also call it in the `init?(coder: NSCoder)`.

Comment: So I revised my code based off your feedback and the comment i received above. However, I am still not seeing the image come up when I run the simulator. I have the class assigned to my navigation controller in my storyboard as well.